# Subversion - need to change the structure of repositories?

Tags: svn

I use Subversion and I think my structure of the repositories is not good.
I have:

```
/repoA
    /project10
    /project11
    /project12
    /project13
    /project14
    ...
/repoB
    /project20
    /project21
    /project22
    ...
```

So I put several projects into one repository which are fully independent to each other. So under the /repoX the "repositories" are only folders.

I think better would be a structure like this where one project is a separeted repository.

```
/repoProject10
/repoProject11
/repoProject12
/repoProject13
...
/repoProject20
/repoProject21
...
```

What do you think? The main problem is the limitation of users to the repositories. I do not want that one user can see repoA/, the user should for example only read and write to /project11 /project22. So I have to limit the paths...
Also there is only one history for one repository, not for a project.

So what do you think, is it better to change the structure and one project is managed by one repository?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just put all your projects in one big repository.

Others are doing the same without problems. For example, the [repository of the apache software foundation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/) contains about a hundred projects (among them subversion itself!) and over a million revisions.

> I do not want that one user can see repoA/, the user should for example only read and write to /project11 /project22. So I have to limit the paths...

Subversion does [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html), so even if you put everything in one repository  you can still manage read/write access separately for each project.

> Also there is only one history for one repository, not for a project.

I'm not sure what you mean there. If you do a `svn log http://example.com/svn/projectA` then you will only see the history of projectA, even if there is a projectB in the same repository.

Perhaps what you mean is that you don't feel comfortable with the way the revision number advances globally for the whole repository. I would suggest to just think of the SVN revision as a time coordinate. Its only meaning is that higher revision numbers happened after lower ones. In fact, you can even do without revision numbers and use [revision dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) instead if you prefer.

Comment: I thought it is perhaps more stable, so if sth. crashes in one repository all projects are affected and if I separate them, I do not have this problem.

Comment: Also, I can manage new repositories if I have a repository for one project. So if someone wants to create a new project, he has to call me, otherwise most people with write access can create a new folder / project and then I can not set the permissions if no one tells me.

Comment: @Tim: 1) not sure what you mean by "crash". If you are talking about limiting the impact of hardware failure and OS crashes, you will have to maintain a lot of separate machines. It might be simpler to just have a fallback machine with a `svnsync`'ed repository. 2) you can give people read-only access to the root `/`, while giving read-write access for a specific project folder `/foo`. That way people cannot create new projects themselves. This is most likely how commit rights in the apache repository work.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply. I think I won't change the structure and do it like you told.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit subjective, but yes, it's not unusual to have each project in it's own repository.

Unless the projects are tiny, and the work to create a new repo is significant compared to the whole project, this is what I would do. (I do have a "random stuff" repository for little tools, scripts and spikes that don't belong anywhere else).

It is also quite possible to manage permissions per reporitory, so I'm not sure what you mean when you worry about that. You can grant any particular user the permissions you want them to have.

For example, at a client I used to work at, we had a structure similar to (simiplified to remove branches/trunk/tags etc):

```
/RepoCoreLibrary

/RepoProject1
    /RepoCoreLibrary <as an svn external>
```

You can then give certain Devs readonly access to the Core, but read and write to their projects. Prevents  junior devs from committing to you core code by accident or without code review.

Comment: The projects within the repository are big projects. So what are the advantages / disadvantages of my structure? I found only disadvantages...

Comment: I think the only possible advantage to sharing repos is that you don't have to create more repos, and set permissions on them. Considering that takes 5 minutes it's not much of an advantage. (or even 10 minutes If, like me, you inevitably have to lookup the syntax first)

Comment: The permission thing is somehow an advantage. If I put all in one repository, the people with write access can create new folders ? projects on the top level and then I can not set permissions if no one will tell me that a new project is created.